# Be careful of vector::reserve?

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int l[] = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> vi(4);
    copy(l, l+4, vi.begin());

    do_stuff();
}
```

The above code can compile and run without no errors. Then I changed it into this:

```
int main()
{
    int l[] = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> vi;
    vi.reserve(4);  //different from the above code
    copy(l, l+4, vi.begin());

    do_stuff();
}
```

According to the code, I changed `vector<int> vi(4);` into `vector<int> vi; vi.reserve(4);`, **but** the problem comes, that is, the changed code can compile, but a seg-fault occurs when it runs.

According to `gdb`, the seg-fault occurs in function `do_stuff();`.

Why is that? Does the change I made matter? Can't I use `reserve` here?

Comment: You probably intended to call `vi.resize(4)`, rather than `vi.reserve(4)`. However, as in your first piece of code, this would needlessly initialize the vector with four `0` elements. It's better to `reserve()` and use `std::back_inserter` or initialize it with the correct data right away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `reserve()` method only allocates memory, but leaves it uninitialized. It only affects `capacity()`, but `size()` will be unchanged.

If you want to create as many instances you should use `resize()` which allocates memory, and also creates as many instances as the argument passed to `resize()`.

Comment: But in both of them, `vi.size()` should be `4` after `copy(...)`, right?

Comment: @Alcott: No. copy only copies, it will not resize() the vector. It only has the iterators at hand. It is as if you write over the boundaries of an array.

Comment: @Alcott: if you don't believe Als that "size will be unchanged", then test it. `vector<int> vi; vi.reserve(4); std::cout << vi.size() << '\n';`. It prints `0`.

Comment: The code that fails creates a vector with *room for* four elements. The code that works creates a vector with four elements.

Comment: @Alcott: If you want `copy` to insert into the array, you can use `back_inserter(vi)` as the destination iterator.

Comment: @PlasmaHH How could `copy` resize the vector? It doesn't even know that the vector exists; all it sees are iterators.

Comment: @JamesKanze: "it will not resize() the vector. It only has the iterators at hand"

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that what you actually want to achieve is initialize a vector with a list of elements. This is easily achieved in C++11 with the new list-initialization syntax:

```
std::vector<int> vi {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

If your compiler does not support this syntax yet, you can use the good old range constructor:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> vi(a + 0, a + 4);
```

If for some reason you really want to reserve space and then push the elements back later, write this:

```
std::vector<int> vi;
vi.reserve(4);
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::copy(a + 0, a + 4, std::back_inserter(vi));   // need to #include <iterator>
```

Comment: Well-rounded answer, :). BTW, the new list-initialization syntax `std::vector<int> vi = {1,2,3,4};` doesn't call `vector<int>`'s copy-ctor?

Comment: Good point, I changed copy-list-initialization to direct-list-initialization. But it probably won't make any difference in practice.

Comment: If you really want to see through the OP's true intentions, you should recommend `reserve` plus `back_inserter` plus `std::iota` :-)

Comment: @FredOverflow, direct-list-init is a new syntax, isn't it? I never see it before, nor do I init any vector that before.

Comment: @Alcott It's a C++11 language feature.

Answer (score 1):

From one particular [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/):

> In any case, a call to [vector::reserve] never affects the elements contained in the vector, nor the vector size (for that purposes, see [vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) or [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector%3a%3aerase), which modify the vector size and content).

Comment: Please don't call that crappy error ridden site "the C++ documentation". People could think that it is something official.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you don't need `reserve` and `copy`, because `assign` is sufficient here:

```
int main()
{
    int l[] = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> vi;
    vi.assign(l, l + 4); 

    do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: For that matter, `vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators.